# Why can I not access my node.js basic public API?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Whenever I try to accesse http://localhost:3000/api/courses it doesn't load at all, just hangs.  I've had a similar problem with React routing not loading any subpages. I'm not sure what could be the reason. I am connected via mobile hotspot but I do not connect to the internet using a proxy.

I've tried different ports with the same result.

```
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    if (req.url === '/') {
        res.write('Hello World');
        res.end();
    }

    if (req.url === '/api/courses') {
        res.write(JSON.stringify([1, 2, 3]));
        res.end();
    }
});

server.listen(3000);

console.log('Listening on port 3000...');
```

Expected result is to show me the array `[1, 2, 3]`. Actual result is that the page just hangs without loading.

Comment: Figured out an answer to my question is not to set the second if req.url to strict equals /api/courses. Anybody have an explanation to why this wasn't working?

Comment: Are you sure that is was because of the `===`  in your case, maybe you had a typo in your URL when testing. You should have added a fallback case to debugg the problem. Something like: `if (req.url === '/') { ... } else if (req.url === '/api/courses') { ... } else { res.write(JSON.stringify({url:req.url}));res.end(); }`

Answer (score 0):

No Changes, It is working fine in my pc, Try once in an incognito window or change port.

```
const http = require("http");

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  if (req.url === "/") {
    res.write("Hello World");
    res.end();
  }

  if (req.url === "/api/courses") {
    res.write(JSON.stringify([1, 2, 3]));
    res.end();
  }
});

server.listen(8080);

console.log("Listening on port 8080...")
```

Check link - https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6mLQ.png

Answer (score -1):

Because you are not returning the valid JSON object.

`res.write(JSON.stringify([1, 2, 3]));`

Try something like this

`res.write(JSON.stringify({"result" :[1, 2, 3])});`

Comment: Why should it be required to return the data in the form `{"result" :[1, 2, 3]}`?   `[1, 2, 3]` is already valid JSON. And why do you do an exact (including the typo) copy and past of another answer?